# sum of exponents

Tags: notation, terminology, integers, prime-factorization

When factorization of integer $x$ is $x=p_{1}^{e_1} p_{2}^{e_{2}} \cdots p_{n}^{e_n}$, I'd like to notate the sum of exponents; $f(x)=e_{1}+e_2 + \cdots +e_{n}$. Is it already defined or named?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OEIS A001222](https://oeis.org/A001222) denotes this as $\Omega(x)$ *"Omega: Number of prime divisors counted with multiplicity"*:

$$\Omega\big(\prod_i p_i^{e_i}\big) := \sum_i e_i$$

FYI, [A001221](https://oeis.org/A001221) denotes the sum of exponents *without* multiplicity as $\omega(x)$ "omega".

Comment: Thanks! Have a good day.